# Returning Date values from Bash script that runs a Perl Script

Tags: perl, bash, datetime, posix

I am trying to fix a script that is supposed to return 3 date values: 1 week ago, 1 month ago and 3 months ago. It uses a Perl module from CPAN called Time::ParseDate but I cannot figure out how it works nor where it is going wrong.

```
getdate(){
echo $* | perl -MPOSIX -MTime::ParseDate -e'print strftime("%D",localtime(parsedate(<>)))'
return 0
}
oneweekago='getdate now - 1week'
onemonthago='getdate now - 1month'
threemonthsago='getdate now - 3month'
```

When I run this from the shell I get this output:

```
-bash-4.1$ oneweekago='getdate now - 1week'
-bash:    : command not found
-bash:    : command not found
-bash-4.1$ onemonthago='getdate now - 1month'
-bash:    : command not found
-bash:    : command not found
-bash-4.1$ threemonthsago='getdate now - 3month'
-bash:    : command not found
-bash:    : command not found
```

I am totally new to unix scripting so I am sure this is  some basic syntax I am missing but I cannot find it. Btw I have already installed the Time::ParseDate module and verified it is installed properly.

Comment: If you have GNU `date(1)`, you can do that right in the shell script, rather than calling the Perl script.

Comment: @Tripp I wish! :) I need to compare the output of this script (when it works properly) to another date calculation. So unfortunately I have to stick with this perl script...

Comment: What happens if you replace the single-quotes with backticks?

Comment: -bash-4.1$ oneweekago=`getdate now - 1week`
-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: command substitution: line 1: `print strftime("%D", localtime(parsedate(<>)))'
No code specified for -e.
-bash:    : command not found
-bash:    : command not found

Comment: Is it possible to escape out your actual backticks so SO doesn't garble your response?

Comment: Your problem is with your "UNIX" script.  Functions cannot return values in the manner you are attempting to use.

What shell are you using Bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to output the values immediately upon calling the function this works for me:

EDIT: Modified to get the return value. You were using single quotes, not backtics.

```
#!/bin/bash

function getdate() {
    echo $* | perl -MPOSIX -MTime::ParseDate -e'print strftime("%D",localtime(parsedate(<>)))'
    return 0
}

oneweekago=$( getdate now - 1week )
# Using backtics this would look like:  oneweekago=`getdate now - 1week`
# However, I prefer $() for clarity.

onemonthago=$( getdate now - 1month)
threemonthsago=$(getdate now - 3month)

#getdate "now - 1week"
#getdate "now - 1month"
#getdate "now - 3month"

echo $oneweekago
echo $onemonthago
echo $threemonthsago
```